# How to get all cookies with urlfetch?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, urlfetch

In accordance with [GAE fetch documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction), cookies are not handled with redirects:

> Cookies are not handled upon redirection. If cookie handling is needed, set follow_redirects to False and handle both cookies and redirects manually.

So, I am trying to implement manual solution:

```
page = urlfetch.Fetch(
    url = url,
    payload = form_data,
    method = urlfetch.POST,
    headers = headers,
    follow_redirects = False,
    deadline = 60)
cookies = ''
while page.status_code == 302:
    url = page.headers.get('location')
    if page.headers.get('set-cookie'):
        cookies = page.headers.get('set-cookie')
        headers['cookie'] = cookies
    page = urlfetch.Fetch(
        url = url,
        method = urlfetch.GET,
        headers = headers,
        follow_redirects = False,
        deadline = 60)
if page.status_code == 200 and page.content:
    self.response.out.write(page.content)
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Looks like I am missing [some cookies](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects):

> header_msg
>       An instance of httplib.HTTPMessage containing the response headers. If there may be multiple headers with the same name (for
>   example, Set-Cookie headers), call header_msg.get_headers(header_name)
>   to retrieve the values as a list.

But how should I use that *header_msg*?

Comment: In what way does it not work as expected? You get some Set-Cookie headers but not all you expect?

Comment: @AdamThomason, looks so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem, you want to collect (and cumulatively pass on) the cookies from each response, but URLFetch with follow_redirects=True only returns the cookies from the last response. Furthermore, the default behavior doesn't implement a cookie jar that will result in latter requests being sent with the right `Cookie` headers corresponding to the `Set-Cookie`s in prior responses. Presumably the initial POST is a login form that redirects to a page expecting the cookie, a scheme which can't work with these limitations.

To that end, your code is close, but `cookies = page.headers.get('set-cookie')` is wiping out previously collected cookies after each request. This should work better:

```
page = urlfetch.Fetch(
  url = url,
  headers = headers,
  follow_redirects = False)
cookies = []
while page.status_code == 302:
  url = page.headers.get('location')
  if page.headers.get('set-cookie'):
    cookies.extend(page.header_msg.getheaders('set-cookie'))
  headers['cookie'] = '; '.join(cookies)
  page = urlfetch.Fetch(
    url = url,
    method = urlfetch.GET,
    headers = headers,
    follow_redirects = False)
if page.status_code == 200 and page.content:
  self.response.out.write(page.content)
```

Some caveats:

- If `Location` is a relative path, you'll need to fix up `url`.
- If any `Set-Cookie` header is not just key=value (e.g. it has an expiration), you'll need to parse the header value so you can send just the key/value pair. See the [Cookie](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html) libraries for assistance with parsing.
- This code will happily send duplicate cookies if more than one `Set-Cookie` was seen for a particular key.
- If the redirect winds up on a separate domain, this will incorrectly send it cookies from the original domain. This may be a security problem. A proper cookie jar implementation can reason about domain and path restrictions to determine when to accept and emit cookies. You may want to incorporate the [cookielib.CookieJar](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects) library. If you expect the request sequence to be on the same domain, it may be enough to just abort if you detect a switch.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. This is actually the problem even with your code - `'_URLFetchResult' object has no attribute 'header_msg'`. I use python 2.5.

Comment: This works for me under python 2.5 and python 2.7. Are you using the latest python SDK?